# Issue in adding Hint for AutoCompleteTextView in Android with android:hint="" function

Tags: android

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/edtname">
```

I have tried `android:hint` and `android:CompletionHint`, but unable to show hint text on the AutocompleteTextView.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Set this on xml:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_conten"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="HintYouWantToGive" />
```

Comment: Thank You . I tried it earlier , it shows the hint in the design , but its not working in run time , May be some data in activity over wrights its value . Is there any steps to validate the hint pragmatically (other than sethint which sets the hint only after touching the text view) .

Comment: Sorted out . Thank You . the issue was with the color of the hint and background :)

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute `android:hint` to show `hint` text. You should use different `color` for `hint text` and `background`.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="This is a hint"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >        
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Comment: Thank You . I tried it earlier , it shows the hint in the design , but its not working in run time , May be some data in activity over wrights its value . Is there any steps to validate the hint pragmatically (other than sethint which sets the hint only after touching the text view) .

Comment: Sorted out . Thank You . the issue was with the color of the hint and background :)

Comment: Ohh I see, This is a common mistake. You should use different color for hint text and background. Btw, happy to know its working...

Answer (score 0):

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="**Your Hint**" />
```

Comment: Thank You . I tried it earlier , it shows the hint in the design , but its not working in run time , May be some data in activity over wrights its value . Is there any steps to validate the hint pragmatically (other than sethint which sets the hint only after touching the text view) .

Comment: Sorted out . Thank You . the issue was with the color of the hint and background :)

Comment: ok... welcome...